git, create a branch from old commit and add some new commits
Let's say I have a branch with 5 commits in main:
The older: A
Then: B, C, D
And the latest: E
I need to rollback to the hash "B", but also, I need the changes of the commit "D" and "E".
I can't do this:
git checkout main
git pull origin main
git checkout B
git cherry-pick D
git cherry-pick E

Doing that git will return fatal: bad object because D and E are not in the log.
How can I rollback to a certain hash, but also pick 2 newer commits?

The shown command sequence is nothing out of the ordinary and should work, provided you used reasonable values for the commit IDs. Show the history and commit graph: git log --graph --oneline main and the exact commands, including commit IDs, and the exact error message.

It's not about the commits being newer that is causing the problem. skipping commits is something that is ok (it can easily be done using an interactive rebase). Can we see in the question the output of git log --graph --oneline --all and the commands you are running and their outputs?

It's like @j6t and I are clones :-D

I have realized that I had to use (in my case) the "squash commits". There's a bot that after each merged PR deletes the original branch, and add it's own commit, with a different hash. Using those on the cherry worked fine. Thanks for the comments.

@eftshift0 And I'm your bare clone, guys ;'-)

So, @pmiranda, you got it?

@RomainValeri :-D

I have realized that I had to use (in my case) the "squash commits". There's a bot that after each merged PR deletes the original branch, and add it's own commit, with a different hash. Using those on the cherry worked fine. Thanks for the comments.
